# How to query specific information for an issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, python-jira

I'm trying to use JIRA python api to receive the list of tickets that have been raised in the last 30 days but whenever i run

```
Issue = main.jira.issue("PLAT-38592")
i = main.jira.issue(issue, "Summary")
print(i)
```

All that gets returned is

```
PLAT-38592
```

Then i try to poke at the issue

```
Issue = main.jira.issue("PLAT-38592")
print (Issue)
```

And all that gets returned is

```
PLAT-38592
```

I need to be able receive information from this ticket but it only returns a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues are objects. You can access their content by accessing fields.

If you for example want to access the summary, you can use (according to [the docs](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#issues)):

```
issue = jira.issue('PLAT-38592', fields='summary')
summary = issue.fields.summary
print(summary)
```